# How to create an instance with local ssd attached with gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I try to use python googleapiclient to create an instance with a boot disk and a local ssd disk.
This is a gcp image for a build system and i want better performance

```
def create_instance(compute, image_name):
    image_response = compute.images().get(project=GCP_PROJECT_ID,
                                          image=GCP_IMAGE_NAME).execute()
    source_disk_image = image_response['selfLink']
    machine_type = f"zones/{GCP_ZONE}/machineTypes/n2-standard-4"
    config = {
        'name': image_name,
        'machineType': machine_type,

        # Specify the boot disk and the image to use as a source.
        'disks': [
            {
                'boot': True,
                'autoDelete': True,
                'initializeParams': {
                    'sourceImage': source_disk_image,
                }
            },
            {
                'boot': False,
                'autoDelete': True,
                'initializeParams': {
                    'disk_type': 'local-ssd'
                }
            }
        ],

        # Specify a network interface with NAT to access the public
        # internet.
        'networkInterfaces': [{
            'network': 'global/networks/default',
            'accessConfigs': [
                {'type': 'ONE_TO_ONE_NAT', 'name': 'External NAT'}
            ]
        }],

        # Allow the instance to access cloud storage and logging.
        'serviceAccounts': [{
            'email': 'default',
            'scopes': [
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
            ]
        }]
    }

    operation = compute.instances().insert(
        project=GCP_PROJECT_ID,
        zone=GCP_ZONE,
        body=config).execute()
    return operation
```

As. hard i try to give different initializeParams diskTypes it always creates me a standard persistent 500GB disk and not a local ssd. I tried already:

- local-ssd
- https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project/zones/zone/diskTypes/local-ssd
- https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project/zones/us-central1-a/diskTypes/local-ssd

but nothing helped.

What do i wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [official GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/local-ssd#create_local_ssd) on creating an instance with a Local SSD, and referencing Google's API, we can view the following:

[image: Description of API]

In addition to the above information, this below is a sample request payload that creates an instance with a boot disk and a local SSD device:

[image: sample request payload]

In comparison to your payload request using Python Google's API Client, it would seem that your not specifying the "type" of each disk. The API requires for the local SSD to be type "*SCRATCH*", where as the bootable disk needs to be type "*PERSISTENT*". Try doing this and see if it has any affect.

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation [1, local SSDs are located on the physical machine where your virtual machine instance is running, they can be created only during the instance creation process. Local SSDs cannot be used as boot devices.

After creating a local SSD, we must format and mount the device [2] before we use it.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/local-ssd#create_local_ssd

[2] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/local-ssd#format_and_mount_a_local_ssd_device

Comment: I issue here an instance creation command. I pass as parameter that bootable is false. What is wrong in my code?